# Bash Script- Bash Script - Editing Lines on Text From File

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using a bash script to read in data from a text file.

Data:

```
04:31 Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven http://goo.gl/rMOa2q 
[ARMADA MUSIC]

07:46 Fabio XB & Liuck feat. Christina Novelli - Back To You (Wach Remix)http://goo.gl  /yGxqRX 
[DIGITAL SOCIETY RECORDINGS]
```

code:

```
#!/bin/bash


file="/home/nexusfactor/Desktop/inputData(linux).txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
       # display $line or do somthing with $line
       echo "$line"
done <"$file"
```

I would like to remove the white space between the two songs, then remove the time at the beginning of the song and the hyperlink/studio name from the end of the file. So my output would be:

```
Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven
Fabio XB & Liuck feat. Christina Novelli
```

Comment: Read up on `sed` and `awk`. Those command will be useful here.

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/574137/bash-script-editing-lines-on-text-from-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/nexusfactor/Desktop/inputData(linux).txt"
while read -r date line
do
  [[ $date == "" ]] && continue    # empty line -> next loop
  [[ $date =~ ^\[ ]] && continue   # line starts with "[" -> next loop
  line="${line%(*}"                # remove "(" and everything to the right of it
  line="${line%http*}"             # remove "http" and everything to the right of it
  echo "$line"
done <"$file"
```

Output:

```
Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven 
Fabio XB & Liuck feat. Christina Novelli - Back To You
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'  line 10: `done <"$file'

Comment: Thanks, so much for this, however, one more requirement, is it possible to remove the studio name in the [] after the link? Completely remove it, including the braces?

Comment: I've added output of my script. The output contains already no `[studio]` because these brackets are behind a `(` or `http`.

Comment: Thanks. The mistake was on my end. If you bare with me, let me correct my input data. The studio was initially on a new line.

Comment: I edited my post. The [studio] names were on a line by themselves. How would I remove it so that I get the output you've shown?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo " 04:31 Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven http://goo.gl/rMOa2q [ARMADA MUSIC]

07:46 Fabio XB & Liuck feat. Christina Novelli - Back To You (Wach Remix) http://goo.gl/yGxqRX [DIGITAL SOCIETY RECORDINGS]" \
| sed '/^[ \t]*$/d;s/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] //;s/http:.*//'
```

**output**

```
Alex M.O.R.P.H. & Natalie Gioia - My Heaven
Fabio XB & Liuck feat. Christina Novelli - Back To You (Wach Remix)
# ---------------------------------------^----- ????
```

Not quite what your example output shows, but matches your written requirement 
*remove the time at the beginning of the song and the hyperlink/studio name from the end ...*

Rather than read each line in a while loop, use `sed`s built in ability to read each line of a file and process it. you can do

```
sed '/^[ \t]*$/d;s/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] //;s/http:.*//' file > newFile && /bin/mv newFile file
```

OR if you're using a modern linux environment (and others), use the `-i` option to overwrite the existing file :

```
sed -i '/^[ \t]*$/d;s/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] //;s/http:.*//' file
```

IHTH

Comment: My example output is me just typing what I wanted, but your output is what I wanted anyway :D. Now wait, how would I apply it to my while loop so that as it reads each line, it edits it?

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm using Lubuntu 14.10, I'm going to try the last example.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield with the `-i` option you can also keep a backup of the original file if you want `sed -i .bak '/^[..etc..' file`. See `man sed`.